# Perl structure flow to C

Tags: c, perl, data-structures

I've started working on a program which is in Perl and has to be transformed into C.

There are a lot of subroutines which have structure member accessing which is unfamiliar to me, because I have little to no knowledge about Perl syntax and structure flow.
Example:

```
$ref->{$struct2[$value]->{field1}}->{struct_insideStruct2}->{$ref2->{field}}
```

$ref is a third structure

$ref2 is a local copy of a parameter which is of type struct1

My question is: How do you create a line like this in C?

Do I need to create nested multiple structures?

I need to understand how multiple access operators in Perl works and if I can create something similiar in C, thanks in advance.

Comment: `$ref2->{field}` is a hash table lookup. So you need to create a hash table, see for example [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/hash_table_program_in_c.htm) page for an example of how to create one.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to write that in C?  It is hellacious to emulate that.  Perl will probably do it faster; it has had decades of experts optimizing it.  Review what you have to transform that code into C.  Then, I strongly recommend you decide that it does not need to be transformed into C.

Comment: I know, but sadly I do need to do it in C, or at least make it similar. But the previous comment by Hakon gives me an idea, that I might need a hash table for this problem. I agree for the part about Perl, it's just the task requiring it, otherwise I would not do it

Comment: It's hard to judge what a C implementation would look like from just one line given out of context. `$ref2->{field}` is a hash table lookup, but on a constant key. If you have only few keys, you might by able to use a struct, so that the C code would be `ref2->field`.

Comment: Instead of replicating the Perl logic, figure out the best way to represent your data in the C program. From that, use whatever access techniques make sense for the problem. Or, embed a perl interpreter in your C program.

Comment: AS a rule of thumb you will need six to twenty lines of C code for every line of perl.

Comment: @JamesAnderson Well, except that it is much much worse here given what would be needed to do, with multiple nesting of things.  Effectively they'd need to implement a library for this one line.

Comment: Given that there is no direct equivalent of a C struct in perl, and perl programmers commonly fake structures using hashes a C implementation would need perhaps three structs and  only two associative arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to not try to directly translate between languages, as this likely results in a clumsy and unnatural code. That would certainly be the case here, as commented further down. The best I can do for this quest is to explain what the expression does

```perl
$ref -> { $struct2[$value]->{field1} }
     -> { struct_insideStruct2 }
     -> { $ref2->{field} }
```

The `$ref` is a [reference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut) to a [hash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata) (associative array); it's OK to think of it as a pointer to a hash. One can tell because the `->` ("arrow") operator [*dereferences*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#The-Arrow-Operator), and the `{...}` on its right means that on its left there must be a hash reference; this returns a value that it points to.

In this case, the key with which it is dereferenced (the index into the associative array) involves an element of the array `@struct2` at index `$value`; that element is another hash reference, being dereferenced (indexed into) with a key `field1` (string literal<sup>†</sup>).

What this returns is another hash reference, which is then indexed into (dereferenced) with the key `struct_insideStruct2` (string), and this again returns a hash reference.

That last one is indexed with a key which itself is produced by dereferencing another hash reference, `$ref2`, with a key `field` (string).

This is an example of a Perl [complex data structure](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc). How do you like it?  I don't, not very much. Even in Perl, ideally I'd like to see this rewritten as a class, as it goes too deep and wide and so it packs too much complexity without any supporting structure which a class can provide.

If you still wish to indeed and really do that kinda thing in C, you *can*. May want to find a good hash implementation (or use `struct`s and nest them carefully), and probably to dust off your function pointer syntax and such. But I would recommend to not get into all that.

Instead, once you understand the deep-nested data structure explained above, and the data it represents, find a way to implement what it means and does in your code in a native C way. We always want to use logic, techniques, and idioms native to the language at hand.

Along with linked documentation also see the short and sweet [perlintro](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro).  The full reference for Perl's references is [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref).

---

<sup>†</sup>  Normally such "barewords" need be under quotes, `'string'` (or using `""`, or `q()` or `qq()` operators ...). But if that is a sole thing between `{}` then the quoting may be omitted.

Comment: @Gadr1 I hope this helps, even as it doesn't give you an equivalent C code.  That'd be a bit of a grand undertaking, which I recommend against (along with other poeple) -- and which we couldn't do without knowing what that program does.  Please let me know if more clarification can help

Comment: I decided to go for Hash table, because I need it only for an if statement to find a record and check its value. It allowed me to search for that record and check out the value for a function it needed. Thanks for the comments and help guys, since it's my first question on stackoverflow

Comment: @Gadr1 Great, that's one way I meant it -- find a hash implementation (is that what you mean?), and more to the point understand your data and work with it so to not have to blindly "translate."  It's a good question and how you posed it I think, it's just  that the whole proposition itself difficult.